# Can not install Flutter on MacOs, Tells that the unzip process is not working

Tags: flutter, installation

When I try to install

> unzip ~/Downloads/flutter_macos_2.2.2-stable.zip

this message pops up

> unzip:  cannot find or open /Users/user/Downloads/flutter_macos_2.2.2-stable.zip, /Users/user/Downloads/flutter_macos_2.2.2-stable.zip.zip or /Users/user/Downloads/flutter_macos_2.2.2-stable.zip.ZIP.

I don't what to do to install Flutter to OSX (vscode)
I can obtain flutter for Android Studio with no problems.
Also can't access flutter by itself on iTerm or Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that your archive has two extensions `.zip.zip`, but it's probably not the problem you're facing.

You may want to check if your iTerm has the necessary permissions to access the content of the folder "Download" since it's a special folder for MacOS.

Second, for creating a flutter project through VSCode, you need to run the command `flutter create myprojectnamehere`, you will not have a button to create a flutter project like on Android Studio.

If you still facing issues with the installation of Flutter, you may want to checkout [Flutter_Installer](https://github.com/YazeedAlKhalaf/Flutter_Installer) which is a Flutter GUI Installer made with Flutter.

Comment: Thanks for the information on installing Flutter. My other problem is not  able to bring up flutter only with Android Studio. I have created several PATHs for incorporating flutter to the $PATH. Until I resolve the flutter question, I won't be able to install flutter on vscode. I have looked at all Q/A on this matter and tried everything. This came about after last upgrade of Big Sur, and apple support was at a loss to explain why the problem exists. I have done every thing possible that other users have written. I was told that reinstall of Big Sur would/might solve it.

Comment: I am also on Big Sur, without any problem, you just have to update your PATH environment variable in your .zshrc file.
`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/blkkkbvsik/Documents/flutterSDK/bin"`

Comment: BLKKKBVSIK: hear what I did to the $PATH

Comment: oops..
Export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
/path-to-flutter-sdk/bin/flutter:$PATH
  anyway It didn't work still no response in either Terminal or Iterm

Comment: you don't have to add the /flutter at the end of your path `path-to-flutter-sdk/bin/flutter` to `path-to-flutter-sdk/bin`

Comment: ~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/user/development/flutter/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
➜After applying your input to the PATH, the above is what I get. Nothing has changed

Comment: After invoking the additions to $PATH, I still come up with the following:➜  ~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/user/development/flutter/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
➜

Comment: which flutter...user/local/bin/flutter...looks like it is in the PATH

Comment: BLKKKBVSIK, Thank you so much for your help. My problem is not having the fultterSDK in the PATH env.  Good "luck" in your education and future projects.